# Polymer and Firebase: changing the path of <firebase-query> dynamically

Tags: asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I have a  in a component, which fetches some data. The path is dynamic, as it has a binding inside it.

I then have some links that change the path dynamically. I would expect the list of data to update accordingly.

when I first load the page, it works all fine, but whenever I click on a link to update the path (and therefore to fetch new data), it returns nothing.

I checked what was going on with an observer, and it looks like whenever I update the path the data is updated twice: first it returns the actual data I would expect, and then it returns an empty array.

Here is the component:

```
<dom-module id="test-one">

  <template>

    <firebase-query app-name="main" path="/templates/[[template]]" data="{{items}}"></firebase-query>

    <a on-tap="changeTemplate" data-template="template1">Template 1</a><br />
    <a on-tap="changeTemplate" data-template="template2">Template 2</a><br />

    <p>Current template is [[template]]</p>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
      [[item.ref]] - [[item.description]]<br />
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-one',
      properties: {
        items: {type: Array, observer: "dataChanged"},
        template: {type: String, value: "template1"},
      },
      dataChanged: function(newData, oldData) {
        console.log(newData);
      },
      changeTemplate: function(e) {
        elm = e.currentTarget;
        template = elm.getAttribute("data-template");
        console.log("link has been clicked, we're changing to "+template);
        this.set("template", template);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

This is what the console shows when I click on one of the links:

[image]

There seems to be some asynchronious sorcery going on - any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue but you should set template like this: this.set('template', template)

Comment: Also a regular observer takes 2 arguments.  oldValue and newValue.  I think you are logging the old value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried to use this.set('template', template) and also to add the two arguments to the observer, but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work. I've updated my post with these changes.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I changed something, I forget what, from one way binding [[ to two way {{.  I would try the [[template]] in the path first

Comment: Thanks again for the tip, Ryan. I've tried changing all the variables from one way to two way binding, but alas, still no luck.

Comment: Try changing template = elm.getAttribute("data-template"); to localTemplate = elm.getAttribute("data-template");

Comment: Alas, still no luck when I try to change template to localTemplate...

Comment: Same exact problem! Let me know if you find a fix.

Comment: Working on tracking this down, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively a bug in **firebase-query**, fixed with this pull request: 
https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/pull/167.

It has already been reported here: https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/100

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **this is a bug in Polymerfire**. For now making the following changes to your local copy of `firebase-database-behavior.html` will fix the problem, seemingly without artifacts, however this really requires a bug report. I will get to filling a bug report as soon as I get a chance, they tend to have a lot of time consuming back and forth :(

Simply comment out line 86 in `firebase-database-behavior.html`. The new `__pathChanged` function should look as so.

```js
__pathChanged: function(path, oldPath) {
  if (oldPath != null && !this.disabled && this.__pathReady(path)) {
    this.syncToMemory(function() {
      // this.data = this.zeroValue;
    });
  }
},
```

### What's Going On

When the path changes there is code written to zero out the old value, and this code lives in `firebase-databse-behavior.html`, which `firebase-query` inherits. This makes sense, however `firebase-query` already zeros out the data upon `__queryChanged` at line 279 in `firebase-query.html`.

```js
__queryChanged: function(query, oldQuery) {
  if (oldQuery) {
    oldQuery.off('child_added', this.__onFirebaseChildAdded, this);
    oldQuery.off('child_removed', this.__onFirebaseChildRemoved, this);
    oldQuery.off('child_changed', this.__onFirebaseChildChanged, this);
    oldQuery.off('child_moved', this.__onFirebaseChildMoved, this);

    this.syncToMemory(function() {
      this.set('data', this.zeroValue);
    });
  }

  if (query) {
    query.on('child_added', this.__onFirebaseChildAdded, this.__onError, this);
    query.on('child_removed', this.__onFirebaseChildRemoved, this.__onError, this);
    query.on('child_changed', this.__onFirebaseChildChanged, this.__onError, this);
    query.on('child_moved', this.__onFirebaseChildMoved, this.__onError, this);
  }
},
```

Changes to the path are first observed by `firebase-query` by `__computeQuery` at line 23 in `firebase-query.html`. `__queryChanged` is then triggered zeroing out the old data and sets up firebase event handlers to observe changes to the firebase database. Subsequently, `__pathChanged` in `firebase-database-behavior.html` is called which again zeros out the data, but after the new data has already been written by the firebase event handlers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Marc for catching that one and for your solution, that's much appreciated! I've marked krikrou's link to the firebase-query pull request as the solution just because that seems to be the "official" way to solve the issue, but you're the one who caught it, thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like we are all doing the same thing to fix this, getting rid of `__pathChanged`. Hopefully this fix gets accepted sometime this century :)